# How to set an Image border on BlackBerry Screen

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have a List Items(an Image and text)on BB Screen,
My requirement is to set an image border(So that Image Separation will be done on List Items) to image on BB Screen
Could any one help?

Here My Code:

```
public void drawListRow(ListField list, Graphics g, int index, int y,
            int width) {
        String title = (String) listElements.elementAt(index);

        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) listImage.elementAt(index);


            int LEFT_OFFSET = 2;
            int TOP_OFFSET = 8;
            int xpos = LEFT_OFFSET;
            int ypos = TOP_OFFSET + y;
            int w = image.getWidth();
            int h = image.getHeight();      

            g.drawBitmap(xpos, ypos, w, h, image, 4, 6);

            xpos = w + 20;
            g.setFont(myFont);

            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            g.drawText(title, xpos, ypos);

}
```

Comment: What do you need help with?  It seems you already have working paint code - just change the x,y positions to add more border to the bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope i got your question right and would suggest you drawing a rectangle around the image like that:

```
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.drawRect(xpos - 1, ypos - 1, w + 1, h + 1);
```

This would draw the rectangle around your image without overlapping it. For more details on why you need these adjustments of the position and the size of the rectangle you can check on the documentation of Graphics class here http://www.it.uc3m.es/florina/docencia/j2me/midp/docs/api/javax/microedition/lcdui/Graphics.html